# Zooming of specific area in chart of win form

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization, mschart

I have Win form application in C# which contain `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`.

I want to zoom particular area or Datapoint in ChartDisplay area.

Note: Zooming of area in chart, not whole chart zooming.

Answer (score 1):

Have chart selected. In properties window, select `ChartAreas`. In ChartArea Collection editor, select (in the right properties view) `Cursor`. For `CursorX`, set these properties to true: `IsUserEnabled` and `IsUserSelection`. Repeat for `CursorY`.

Close the windows and run youur app. Now you can zoom in the chart area.

Comment: What could be preventing this from working? I doesn't solve the problem in my case.